# How to generate random variables if they follow a Hawkes process in R or Python?

Tags: python, r

What I found now:

In R, there are hawkesbow and hawkes.
In Python, there are tick.hawkes and hawkeslib.

But I still don't know which function I should use to generate the random variables.

I need some functions, such as rexp in r.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Doesn't [simulateHawkes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hawkes/versions/0.0-4/topics/simulateHawkes) do the thing?

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to generate 100 random variables? I see that in simulateHawkes I can only control horizon.